# get the caller number after call is answered

Tags: asterisk

I have a php script that run when call is answered it's in [macro-blkvm-clr]
 macro. the php get 3 parms the first param should be the caller number this is my line

```
exten => s,n,AGI(/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/alertcalls.php,${CALLERID(num)},1,${MASTER_CHANNEL(CONNECTEDLINE(num))})
```

I don't know why but when it asterisk send the parameter to php it set it to the answered phone. for example ext 300 call to ext 200 and in the log that what I see

```
Executing [s@macro-blkvm-clr:2] AGI("PJSIP/200-00000253", "/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/alertcalls.php,200,1,200") in new stack
```

why is that. and how can I send the real ext that call (in this case 300)

thks for all helper and sorry for my English I hope I was clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the

```
exten => s,n,SET(VAR1=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => s,n,AGI(/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/alertcalls.php,${VAR1},1,${MASTER_CHANNEL(CONNECTEDLINE(num))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase macro executed for CALLED party channel(it was invented to do privacy) before connect called and calling channel.

You can see all variables by do Dumpchan as first priority in macro.

Comment: not so understand what you mean I am still learn the system. but is there a way to get the real caller

Answer (score 0):

Save the caller ID number into a channel variable before you `Answer()` the call, and then reference that.
You should always be able to reference `${CALLERID(num)}`, but if it's not working for you at that point, the above is an easy work around.